# How to downgrade browser versions other than Internet Explorer?

Tags: browsers, cross-browser-testing, configuration-testing

I am looking for a way to downgrade Chrome/Mozilla/Opera. Other than switching between different developer channels, I am not aware of a way to downgrade to a previous stable version of Chrome.

Please recommend any online tool or explain the procedure how to downgrade it.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? For short manual testing cycles or ...?

Comment: From recent experience trying to downgrade to get past problems with Selenium (which have now been fixed): It's very tricky prevent from upgrading and google are extremely aggressive against places where you get get old versions. Probably not worth the hassle, especially when compared to broswerstack the like.

Comment: Hi Niels, Currently we are developing responsive application and client wants that it should support from older versions.That's why i want downgrade the versions.Sorry for late replay

Comment: "I am looking for a way to downgrade Chrome/Mozilla/Opera." There is no real "downgrade" process, other than uninstalling, then installing the desired (older) version.

Comment: See here https://dev.modern.ie/tools/screenshots/  how a web site renders across a selection of common browsers and devices.its a free tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are online services that provide access to older browser versions (Chrome, Firefox, IE, ...) like [testingbot](http://testingbot.com).

To download older versions of Chrome, try this URL: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-unsigned/desktop-W15K3Y/$version/win/chrome-win.zip

Answer (score 3):

Managing multiple browser setups on a single machine sounds like a nightmare.
Also I wonder how many browsers you really need to support, have a look at [Browser market share per version](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0).

I think services like:

- https://www.browserstack.com/
- https://saucelabs.com/features#features-manual-testing
- http://testingbot.com/

Are better suited for your browser testing needs. They offer loads of browser versions to manually or automatically test with.

As an alternative you could setup a [virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install an oldversion of these products in it:

- For firefox look at: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/
- For chrome has a look at: http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/

Most of these modern browsers do automatic updates, be sure to disable this after installing.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window) recommends:

- using different browser versions on different accounts
- creating several installations of a browser

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [this website](https://www.spoon.net/browsers/) i think it is best.

or you have to download the older version browser then install and then you have to disable the automatic update and use it.

or you can use install virtual machine and install specific browser you want in to that VM.